# How to sniff PPP packet with libpcap?

Tags: c, linux, networking, capture

I can capture packets from eth0 interface, and sniff ip packets as follows

```
/* IP header */
struct sniff_ip {
    u_char  ip_vhl;                 /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
    u_char  ip_tos;                 /* type of service */
    u_short ip_len;                 /* total length */
    u_short ip_id;                  /* identification */
    u_short ip_off;                 /* fragment offset field */
    #define IP_RF 0x8000            /* reserved fragment flag */
    #define IP_DF 0x4000            /* dont fragment flag */
    #define IP_MF 0x2000            /* more fragments flag */
    #define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff       /* mask for fragmenting bits */
    u_char  ip_ttl;                 /* time to live */
    u_char  ip_p;                   /* protocol */
    u_short ip_sum;                 /* checksum */
    struct  in_addr ip_src,ip_dst;  /* source and dest address */
};
```

So if need to capture packets from PPP interface, how to define the header struct?

I just notice that, the length of header is 32 bytes in this case.

Comment: I don't think I know of a way to capture "by program" via either libpcap or tcpdump. care to add some more information?

Comment: sorry! I can capture by the ppp

Comment: But I notice that, the target ip of the packet is "0.2.172.16", it is strange, Think 172.16.0.2 is right.

Comment: The problem with the IP being the wrong way around is most probably because you have the Endian incorrect. If I remember correctly there is something strange about how Endian is done under different Operating Systems. According to the RFC, Ethernet uses Big-Endian encoding. You should have a look at what type your OS uses and do the translations accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If, when you capture on the PPP device with libpcap, the `pcap_datalink()` routine returns `DLT_PPP`, then you define the header in the fashion indicated by the entry for `LINKTYPE_PPP`/`DLT_PPP` in [the tcpdump.org link-layer header types page](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html):

> PPP, as per [RFC 1661](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1661) and [RFC 1662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662); if the first 2 bytes are 0xff and 0x03, it's PPP in HDLC-like framing, with the PPP header following those two bytes, otherwise it's PPP without framing, and the packet begins with the PPP header.